# use one part of composite primary key as foreign key

Tags: postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL.

I have a table `accounts` with `account_id` as the primary key. I also have a second table called `relations` with a composite primary key `(follower_id, following_id)`. Each relation must be unique.

```
ALTER TABLE accounts ADD CONSTRAINT users_pk PRIMARY KEY (account_id);
ALTER TABLE relations ADD CONSTRAINT relations_pk PRIMARY KEY (follower_id, following_id);
```

I want to create a foreign key constraint from follower_id (relations) -> account_id (accounts), and the same with following_id.

```
ALTER TABLE relations ADD CONSTRAINT follower_id_fk FOREIGN KEY (follower_id) REFERENCES accounts (account_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

**This foreign key is not accepted by the database.** I get the following error:

> ERROR:  insert or update on table "relations" violates foreign key constraint "follower_id_fk"
> DETAIL:  Key (follower_id)=(4) is not present in table "accounts".

I understand this, because it's a composite primary key.

**What I want to achieve:**

When an account is deleted, I want to delete all the records where the account_id is the follower_id (`ON DELETE CASCADE`) AND where it is the following_id.

I could do this in my nodejs code or with a trigger function, but I don't know what will be the best performance-wise. Does anyone knows a/the best solution?

Comment: It's failing because there is no `account_id` = 4 in `accounts`.

Comment: Oh that's correct, there is some old data in the relations table. So I was interpreting the error wrong?

Comment: Yes, you where. A value for the referencing field has to either be a value in the referenced table or `NULL`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out Adrian! It works now!

Comment: Should have added it can't be `NULL` in your case as `follower_id` is part of a PK and can't be `NULL`.